# SQLite: finding set with specific values

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
PEAK (NAME, ELEV, DIFF, MAP, REGION)
CLIMBER (NAME, SEX)
PARTICIPATED (TRIP_ID, NAME)
CLIMBED (TRIP_ID, PEAK, WHEN_CLIMBED)
```

I need to find **The peaks that Mark and Mary have climbed**

I did this but it doesn't work:

```
        select *
        from participated, climbed
        where participated.name="MARY" or "MARK" and participated.trip_id= climbed.trip_id
```

I also tried doing:

```
Group By name, peak
Having name="MARY" or "MARK"
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Triplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336635/sqlite-doing-a-difference-of-two-columns and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310285/sqlite-finding-set-on-a-limited-set#comment81571126_47310285

Comment: "**doesn't work**" (does that mean smoke is emitted from the desktop? it crashed the server? the answer is wrong by a factor of 1000? I have an error message on the screen?) Please define "**doesn't work**" and you may want to refrain from using that expression in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN

```
    select *
    from participated
    INNER JOIN  climbed ON participated.trip_id= climbed.trip_id
    where participated.name IN ("MARY" , "MARK")
```

OR a proper OR

```
    select *
    from participated
    INNER JOIN  climbed ON participated.trip_id= climbed.trip_id
    where participated.name = "MARY" OR  participated.name =  "MARK"
```

Comment: but according the the question this approach "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find peaks that **both** climed then do

```
select peak
from participated
join climbed on participated.trip_id = climbed.trip_id
group by peak
having sum(name='MARY') > 0
   and sum(name='MARK') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the peak, you can do:

```
select c.peak
from climbed c join
     trip t
     on c.trip_id = t.trip_id
where name in ('MARY', 'MARK')
group by c.peak
having count(distinct name) = 2;
```

Note the use of proper `JOIN` syntax.